# C++ write file sequence guarantee

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems

Lets assume we have the following events in sequence:

1. Open 3GB file
2. Seek to begining
3. Write 512 zero bytes
4. Seek to end, append 64 KB of data (`::write(fd, buff, size)`)
5. Seek to begining, write 512 bytes header (with crc of a header). Close file.
6. Unplug the power cord with risk of having not synced buffers.

Now lets assume the filesystem and a file are survived and file's size is close to 3GB and first 512 bytes are not zeroes, but valid header written on step (4).

Is it guaranteed that 64 KB "tail" is actually stored on disk and available at the end of a file?

In other words, can filesystem actually write (step 5) to disk before (step 4) is written?

Looking for atomic way to mark a file as "in progress" or "valid".

Please suggest a book about physical layer of DB-engines (-;

Comment: No, it´s not guaranteed (that it will work that way).

Comment: @deviantfan so the filesystem might rearrange write() operations and commit half of them to disk and leave other uncommitted? Will fsync() help me? :)